# Ubuntu 20.04 boots to black screen and is not fixed with boot-repair

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, grub

I have a single boot system running Ubuntu 20.04 and have recently ran into issues after restarting my computer where for an unknown reason I started booting to a black screen. I used boot-repair after booting from a live usb but it did not fix the problem.

I've included the output from the paste url, any ideas on what the problem could be?

Output from the paste url:

````
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================





df: /dev/nvme0n1p1: No such file or directory

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme0n1p2,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file


nvme0n1p2 is 97 % full

** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15433): WARNING **: 14:13:48.357: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory

** (org.gnome.Nautilus:15433): WARNING **: 14:13:48.357: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory
Nautilus-Share-Message: 14:13:48.454: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
totem-video-thumbnailer couldn't open file 'file:///tmp/cgpp.mp4'
totem-video-thumbnailer couldn't open file 'file:///tmp/cms.mp4'
Mount nvme0n1p1 on /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2/boot/efi

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p2/etc/default/grub

===================== Reinstall the grub-efi of nvme0n1p2 ======================

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2 grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.04-1ubuntu26.13
modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-25-generic
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2 modprobe efivars

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2 efibootmgr -v before grub install
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,e3fad2db-5b29-4057-b5a8-5722824353aa,0x800,0x100000)/File(EFIUBUNTUSHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0001* UEFI: SanDisk, Partition 2    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(3,0)/USB(0,0)/HD(2,GPT,a09db2b8-b5f6-43ae-afb1-91e0a90189a1,0x6cc954,0x2130)..BO

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2 uname -r
5.15.0-25-generic

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/nvme0n1p1
mv /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2/boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2 efibootmgr -v after grub install
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,e3fad2db-5b29-4057-b5a8-5722824353aa,0x800,0x100000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0001* UEFI: SanDisk, Partition 2    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(3,0)/USB(0,0)/HD(2,GPT,a09db2b8-b5f6-43ae-afb1-91e0a90189a1,0x6cc954,0x2130)..BO

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2 update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-44-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-41-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-40-generic
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p2/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sda: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sda and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sda: /dev/sda already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on nvme0n1p2

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070] from NVIDIA Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 1.00(5.19) from American Megatrends International, LLC.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled - SecureBoot disabled - Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com.
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,e3fad2db-5b29-4057-b5a8-5722824353aa,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* UEFI: SanDisk, Partition 2    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(3,0)/USB(0,0)/HD(2,GPT,a09db2b8-b5f6-43ae-afb1-91e0a90189a1,0x6cc954,0x2130)..BO

728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/bootx64.efi
85fa9d77b929ec4231aba29476574eb6   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/fbx64.efi
469e608783843a701d172242f016c79c   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/mmx64.efi
fa1bf1a7f90a852abe0bdbd089b7f1b0   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
469e608783843a701d172242f016c79c   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p2   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p2   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p2   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: 35398F4F-1805-4463-B3FD-DE22F2A13EF1
            Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1    2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
nvme0n1p2 1050624 2000408575 1999357952 953.4G Linux filesystem
Disk sda: 57.33 GiB, 61555605504 bytes, 120225792 sectors
Disk identifier: A09DB2B8-B5F6-43AE-AFB3-91E0A90189A1
        Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
sda1       64   7129427   7129364  3.4G Microsoft basic data
sda2  7129428   7137923      8496  4.1M EFI System
sda3  7137924   7138523       600  300K Microsoft basic data
sda4  7139328 120225728 113086401 53.9G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:61.6GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:SanDisk Cruzer Blade:;
1:32.8kB:3650MB:3650MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:3650MB:3655MB:4350kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:3655MB:3655MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
4:3655MB:61.6GB:57.9GB:ext4::;
nvme0n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:HS-SSD-E2000 1024G:;
1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
2:538MB:1024GB:1024GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                  PARTLABEL
sda         iso9660  2022-04-19-10-23-19-00                                                    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS amd64 
├─sda1      iso9660  2022-04-19-10-23-19-00               a09db2b8-b5f6-43ae-afb2-91e0a90189a1 Ubuntu 22.04 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sda2      vfat     8D6C-A9F8                            a09db2b8-b5f6-43ae-afb1-91e0a90189a1 ESP                    Appended2
├─sda3                                                    a09db2b8-b5f6-43ae-afb0-91e0a90189a1                        Gap1
└─sda4      ext4     251393d1-1a74-4bc0-95f8-0cce1756b0f3 2579cc7b-3905-554d-a13e-837bf67c0083 writable               
nvme0n1                                                                                                               
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     4423-628E                            e3fad2db-5b29-4057-b5a8-5722824353aa                        EFI System Partition
└─nvme0n1p2 ext4     6dee6b31-ea6b-4e9f-a88a-ecc5301a3dd7 8915e224-7580-4063-b8e7-156427906b61                        

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                               Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2022-05-25.3/crash]  50.1G   0% /var/crash
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2022-05-25.3/log]    50.1G   0% /var/log
/dev/nvme0n1p1                                                504.8M   1% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p2                                                 50.4G  90% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2
/dev/sda1                                                          0 100% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2022-05-25.3/crash] ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2022-05-25.3/log]   ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/nvme0n1p1                                                vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p2                                                ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda1                                                     iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 6dee6b31-ea6b-4e9f-a88a-ecc5301a3dd7 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p2/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   6dee6b31-ea6b-4e9f-a88a-ecc5301a3dd7
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-44-generic   6dee6b31-ea6b-4e9f-a88a-ecc5301a3dd7
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-41-generic   6dee6b31-ea6b-4e9f-a88a-ecc5301a3dd7
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-40-generic   6dee6b31-ea6b-4e9f-a88a-ecc5301a3dd7
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p2/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=6dee6b31-ea6b-4e9f-a88a-ecc5301a3dd7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=4423-628E  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

==================== nvme0n1p2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

================= nvme0n1p2: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 193.737014771 = 208.023535616  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
 617.729202271 = 663.281680384  boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-40-generic                 2
 688.822952271 = 739.618013184  boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-41-generic                 2
 193.737014771 = 208.023535616  boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-44-generic                 1
 688.822952271 = 739.618013184  boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 825.610347748 = 886.492360704  boot/initrd.img                                6
 192.958221436 = 207.187312640  boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-40-generic              1
 193.572082520 = 207.846440960  boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-41-generic              1
 825.610347748 = 886.492360704  boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-44-generic              6
 193.572082520 = 207.846440960  boot/initrd.img.old                            1

=================== nvme0n1p2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18151 Aug 12  2021 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42359 Jan 13  2021 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12894 Jan 13  2021 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Jan 13  2021 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1424 Jan 13  2021 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Jan 13  2021 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Jan 13  2021 41_custom```
````

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with **UEFI**. To fix it you can turn off **PPT** in *UEFI/BIOS* settings and also enable the **Legacy Boot**.

If it does not fix that tell me and also tell me the name of your system and motherboard.

Cheers,
*Muhammad Arslan Nazir*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).